# Docker run -d changes container architecture

Tags: windows, docker, centos, 32bit-64bit

I was trying to install software on 32-bit CentOS 4.8 and ran into a problem. I ran the container using `docker run -d`(or `-itd`). The installation software keeps pointing to a x86_64 folder where it doesn't exist. I was so confused because I'm sure I used the correct CentOS image. I ran `uname -a` and it tells me that my container architecture is 64-bit (x86_64).

I try to run it using `docker run -it` command instead and when I check `uname -a` it correctly shows that I'm using 32-bit image.

[image: The screenshot]

My question is, is there any explanation why `-d` flag changes the architecture?

I'm using Docker version 20.10.5 on Windows 10 (64-bit).

**Edit**: Even when I start a stopped container from `docker run -it` command using `docker start`, it use 64-bit architecture instead. I need to run it using `docker start -i`.